# Assembly bit shifting

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

Given a 32 bit decimal number in `%ecx` and `%edx`, when trying to shift left and right each copy of the original number using `shl` and `shr`  then moving the carry (the bit that was just cut) to a 8 bit register `ah` and `al` to compare if equal, I wrote:

```
movl    $32, %esi   #counter
xor     %eax, %eax
.LOOP:
shl     %ecx
setb    %ah
shr     %edx
setb    %al
cmp     %ah, %al
jnz     .np
decl    %esi
jnz     .LOOP
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? what are you getting ?

Comment: traversing through the bits from each side to compare if equal, program returns 0 for everything except 0 as input

Comment: What OS you are targeting? (Linux 32-bit, Linux 64-bit, DOS, Windows ... ) For most assemblers this is not a working x86 assembly program. How do you define the return value of the program?

Comment: Linux 32-bit. I used 2 printf after the loops to check if the loop was interrupted or not (.np)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing 2 numbers from opposite sides. Your program continues looping while `ecx[i] == edx[32-i]`. So what you're actually doing is checking whether `ecx` contains an inverted value (i.e. with reordered bits) of `edx`. E.g., it will return true for `ecx` with value `0x200000` and `edx` with value `0x400`.

Comment: but once I'm comparing a decimal which is a palindrome in binary, it should return true, as comparing the bits inverted should result in the same number..why doesn't it return true for 3 for example?

Comment: because you are comparing 32-bit numbers (according to the sizes of `ecx` and `edx`). `3` in binary is actually `00000000000000000000000000000011` - so it's not palindrome, the computer doesn't cut off the leading zeros, it's not his job to perform such logic, all he knows is 32 `0`s and `1`s.